# How to use list comprehension to add an element to copies of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

given:

```
template = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
add = ['e', 'f']
k = 'z'
```

I want to use list comprehension to generate

```
[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'z': 'e'},
 {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'z': 'f'}]
```

I know I can do this:

```
out = []
for v in add:
  t = template.copy()
  t[k] = v
  out.append(t)
```

but it is a little verbose and has no advantage over what I'm trying to replace.

This slightly more general [question on merging dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-as-a-single-expression) is somewhat related but more or less says don't.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
[dict(template,z=value) for value in add]
```

or (to use `k`):

```
[dict(template,**{k:value}) for value in add]
```

Comment: the ** is for use the dictionary as keyword arguments http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists