# Add string to dictionary in list comprehension

Tags: python, json, dictionary, list-comprehension

Say I have a list of filenames `files` containing data in json format. To receive the data in a list with an entry for each file, I use a list comprehension:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = [json.load(open(file)) for file in files]
```

Now I was wondering, if there is a way to append the file name `file` to the json data, as if it looked like this:

```
{
  'Some': ['data', 'that', 'has', 'already', 'been', 'there'],
  'Filename': 'filename'
}
```

For my case, `json.load()` returns a `dict`, so I've tried something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071038/add-an-element-in-each-dictionary-of-a-list-list-comprehension). This didn't work out for me, because `files` contains strings and not dictionaries.

#### Edit

For clarification, if `dict.update()` didn't return `None`, this would probably work:

```
>>> data = [dict([('filename',file)]).update(json.load(open(file))) for file in files]
```

Comment: can you show your values in files variable ?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but your question is answered by [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/364696).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here's one way (requires Python 3.5+):

```
import json

data = [{**json.load(open(file)), **{'Filename': file}} for file in files]
```

The syntax `{**d1, **d2}` combines 2 dictionaries, with preference for `d2`. If you wish to add items explicitly, you can simply add an extra item as so:

```
data = [{**json.load(open(file)), 'Filename': file} for file in files]
```

Comment: You don't need to make the inner temp `dict` for the filename just to unpack it immediately, `{**json.load(open(file)), 'Filename': file}` will work just fine.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, Good point. In this case, your option is cleaner.

Comment: It's extendable either way; you can seamlessly mix definitions of individual key/value pairs with the unpacking existing dicts. `{'a': 1, **x, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, **y}` is perfectly legal, and you can add individual elements on as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge a custom dictionary into the one being loaded as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression).

```
data = [{**json.loads("{\"el...\": 5}"), **{'filename': file}} for file in files]
```