# add a pair of key/value for each element of a list of dicts

Tags: python

I have the following data structure:

`db['data'][products']`

Inside that, i have a list of  dicts:

```
[{'name':'John', 'id':1},
 {'name':'Matt', 'id':2}]
```

How to add a fix pair of key/value for each element of list ?

Results should be something like that:

```
[{'name':'John', 'id':1, 'new_key':'new_value'},
 {'name':'Matt', 'id':2, 'new_key':'new_value'}]
```

Thanks

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071038/add-an-element-in-each-dictionary-of-a-list-list-comprehension)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add an element in each dictionary of a list (list comprehension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071038/add-an-element-in-each-dictionary-of-a-list-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with list comprehension:

```
result = [dict(item, **{'new_key':'new_value'}) for item in db['data']['products']]
```

Answer (score 0):

its just a list of dicts, iterate over them and update as needed:

```
for item in db['data']['products']:
    item['new_key'] = 'new_value'
```