# updating items in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to update a specific item in a list of dictionaries based on another value

I have the list of dictionaries

```
Product_id= [{ "id": 342, "count": 10 },
{"id":  345, "count":  20 },
{"id":  546, "count": 30 },
{"id":  324, "count": 40 },
{"id":  789, "count": 50 },
{"id":  675, "count": 60 }]
```

I'd like to increase the "count" of x "id" where "id" == x

For example if "id" == 342 I want to increase the count by 1 so output would be

```
print(Product_id)

[{ "id": 342, "count": 11 },
{ "id":  345, "count":  20 },
{ "id":  546, "count": 30 },
{"id":  324, "count": 40 },
{"id":  789, "count": 50 },
{"id":  675, "count": 60 }]
```

I can bring up the counts but can update() the count...

I've already tried many things and searching stacks etc (and I know my last attempt was way off, below) so any ideas would be welcome

```
for d in Product_id:
    d.update((k + 1, "count") for k, v in d.items() if v\["id"\] == 342)
```

Comment: Others have indicated how to do the update, I'll just remark that a list of dicts may not be optimal here. For example, there could be dicts with duplicate ids. Why don't you create a single dictionary with `id` as the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the entire list of dictionaries and check the element that satisfies your condition.

```
for p in Product_id:
    if p['id'] == 342:
        p['count']+=1
    
print(Product_id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance! It's exactly what I was looking for :) I knew it was a for loop but didn't know how to execute it properly!

Answer (score 2):

### Answer:

There is a really nice and pythonic related answer to your question here --> [Add an element in each dictionary of a list (list comprehension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071038/add-an-element-in-each-dictionary-of-a-list-list-comprehension)

I would approach this using a list comprehesions in python for both readability and for writting succing/pythonic code:

In 1 line:

```py
p_id = [{**dct,**{'count':dct[k]+1}} if dct['id']==342 else dct for dct in Product_id]
```

If you want a slightly more adaptable verison for use in a function etc:

```py
# let x be the value that you want to upate
x = 342
# and k be the key of that value
k = 'count'
p_id = [{**dct,**{k:dct[k]+1}} if dct['id']==x else dct for dct in Product_id]
```

### Explanation:

> 1. Using `if` `else` statemets in list comprehension to return modified `{'key' : 'value'}` pair value if condition is true and simply return the dictionary if it flase.
> 2. You can't assing variables from within list comp as in `value+=1`, howevever flattend form (using both if and else) is still less verbose than non list comprehesion form.
> 3. `**{}` merges to dictionaris with right most replacing the key vluee pari of 'count' this is equivalent:

```py
p_id = [dict(dct,**{k:dct[k]+1}) if dct['id']==x else dct for dct in Product_id]
```

> Which will produce the same result and you may prefer.
> With the left most items where condition is true, if this evaluetes to false then dict if simplyt returned.
> 4. Star star ** unpacks the dictionary, see -->
> [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)
> 5. This this in longer form is eqivalent to:

```py
p_id = [{'id':dct['id'],'count':dct['count']+1} if dct['id']==x else dct for dct in Product_id]
```

> 6 Rightmost item is the for loop itself and replaces:

```py
for item in itterable:
    if some_condition:
        #do some stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have a `list` of `dictionaries`, you can loop through each `dictionary` in the `list`. After this, find the `id` of interest(here it is `342`). Then increment the `count` of that dictionary by `1`.

This is how you can do it:

```
Product_id= [{ "id": 342, "count": 10 },
{"id":  345, "count":  20 },
{"id":  546, "count": 30 },
{"id":  324, "count": 40 },
{"id":  789, "count": 50 },
{"id":  675, "count": 60 }]

x = 342
for item in Product_id:
    if item["id"] == x:
        item["count"] += 1 
        # You can add a break here if there's only one item to update.
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 342, 'count': 11}, {'id': 345, 'count': 20}, {'id': 546, 'count': 30}, {'id': 324, 'count': 40}, {'id': 789, 'count': 50}, {'id': 675, 'count': 60}]
```

Comment: This will work although I would add a *break* after the value increment **unless** there's a possibility of more dictionaries with the same 'id'

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
for dic in Product_id:
    if dic["id"] == id:
         dic["count"] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance! It's exactly what I was looking for :) I knew it was a for loop but didn't know how to execute it properly!