# Adding a Key:Values in list of dictionaries in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary as below

```
my_list = [
{'Overall': 'PASS', 'subjects': 4, 'student_id': '90e263', 'data': {'Social': 71, 'Science': 55, 'Maths': 99, 'French': 79}}, 
{'Overall': 'FAIL', 'subjects': 4, 'student_id': '90e264', 'data': {'Social': 56, 'Science': 18, 'Maths': 61, 'French': 49}}
]
```

And I would like to add a key:value pair `'class': 'Third Standard'` to all the dictionaries inside the list making the resultant list look like below -

```
my_list = [
{'Overall': 'PASS', 'subjects': 4, 'student_id': '90e263', 'data': {'Social': 71, 'Science': 55, 'Maths': 99, 'French': 79}, 'class': 'Third Standard'}, 
{'Overall': 'FAIL', 'subjects': 4, 'student_id': '90e264', 'data': {'Social': 56, 'Science': 18, 'Maths': 61, 'French': 49}, 'class': 'Third Standard'}
]
```

Note - This is a sample list with just two dictionaries but I've got 1000s of dictionaries in my actual list.

Can someone please help me with best way to update all dictionaries inside the list?

Comment: Iterate over the list, and set the `'class'` key of each item in the list to `'Third Standard'`. There is no _"best way"_ without more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dictionary union operator with a list comprehension:

```py
[entry | {"class": "Third Standard"} for entry in my_list]
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to modify the dictionaries in-place, you can use a simple `for` loop:

```py
for entry in my_list:
    entry["class"] = "Third Standard"
```

---

This produces:

```py
[
    {
        "Overall": "PASS",
        "subjects": 4,
        "student_id": "90e263",
        "data": {
            "Social": 71,
            "Science": 55,
            "Maths": 99,
            "French": 79
        },
        "class": "Third Standard"
    },
    {
        "Overall": "FAIL",
        "subjects": 4,
        "student_id": "90e264",
        "data": {
            "Social": 56,
            "Science": 18,
            "Maths": 61,
            "French": 49
        },
        "class": "Third Standard"
    }
]
```

Comment: There's really no point in creating a whole new list with all new dictionaries when OP just needs to modify their originals in a simple loop.

Comment: Fair point. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Please also try looking for duplicates before adding an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071038/add-an-element-in-each-dictionary-of-a-list-list-comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the list and add value to dictionary:

```py
my_list = [
    {'Overall': 'PASS', 'subjects': 4, 'student_id': '90e263', 'data': {'Social': 71, 'Science': 55, 'Maths': 99, 'French': 79}}, 
    {'Overall': 'FAIL', 'subjects': 4, 'student_id': '90e264', 'data': {'Social': 56, 'Science': 18, 'Maths': 61, 'French': 49}}
]

for d in my_list:
    d["class"] = "Third Standard"
```

Comment: Please try looking for duplicates before adding an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071038/add-an-element-in-each-dictionary-of-a-list-list-comprehension Such basic questions are bound to have duplicates