# Update dictionary in a list

Tags: python

I have list of dictionaries like:

```
>>> lst = [
...     {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
...     {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
... ]
>>> [x for x in lst]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]
```

and I'd like to add new item to each dictionary:

```
>>> [x.update({'c': '0'}) for x in lst]
[None, None]
```

So how to do this?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I took the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197342/how-to-use-list-comprehension-to-add-an-element-to-copies-of-a-dictionary/3197365#3197365: `[dict(x, **{'c': 0}) for x in lst]`, but just wow..., isn't there a nicer way?

Comment: `{'c': '0', **x}` in Python 3.5

Comment: Personally limited to 2.7...